# Form Refactoring Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am currently creating a form in my rails application but would like some advice on refactoring it. The form is being used to save bagel toppings for an order. The user can select three different toppings (topping1, topping2, and topping3), and the form fields for each one are virtually identical.

ie.

```html
<%= form_for order_item, remote: true do |f| %>
  
...
  
  
<div class="field">
   <%= f.label :topping1 do %>
    <%= image_tag("http://www.189harwood.com/statics/images/products/ingredients/butter.png", class:"topping") %>
    Butter
   <% end %>
   <%= f.radio_button :topping1, "butter", checked: "checked" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :topping1 do %>
    <%= image_tag("http://www.wpclipart.com/food/dairy/cheese/soft_cream_cheese.png", class:"topping") %>
    Cream Cheese
   <% end %>
   <%= f.radio_button :topping1, "cream cheese" %>
  </div>
              
              ...
              
              <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :topping2 do %>
    <%= image_tag("http://www.189harwood.com/statics/images/products/ingredients/butter.png", class:"topping") %>
    Butter
   <% end %>
   <%= f.radio_button :topping2, "butter", checked: "checked" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :topping2 do %>
    <%= image_tag("http://www.wpclipart.com/food/dairy/cheese/soft_cream_cheese.png", class:"topping") %>
    Cream Cheese
   <% end %>
   <%= f.radio_button :topping2, "cream cheese" %>
  </div>
              
              ...
              
              
 <%= f.submit "Wrap It Up" %>
<% end %>
```

Any suggestions on how I can refactor this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the toppings in an array of hashes in your model:

```
def self.toppings
    [{name:'butter', url:'http://www.189harwood.com/statics/images/products/ingredients/butter.png'}, {name:'cream cheese', url:'http://www.wpclipart.com/food/dairy/cheese/soft_cream_cheese.png'}, {...}]
end
```

In your controller:

```
my_action
   @topping_options = Model.toppings
end
```

And in your view:

```
<div class="field">
    <% @topping_options.each do |topping| %>
       <%= f.label topping[:name].to_sym, topping[:name].humanize %>
       <%= image_tag(topping[:url], class:"topping") %>
       <%= f.radio_button topping[:name].to_sym %> 
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot better